# How can I know that SPList is archived with System Account?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

To Everyone,

Is there the way to know that a SPList is archived with System Account?

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by archive?

you can use the SPList.Author to find out if the System Account Created that list.

is this what you need? if not can you elaborate please.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks but it's not my mention.
I wanna know whether the current user access to SPList is a System User or not.